# Is there a way to check if a string contains special characters?

Tags: python

I want to know if there is a way to check for special characters in a string. To my knowledge, there is no built-in function to do it, like `.isnumeric()` or `.isdigit()`

For example, with an entry `Test!`  I want the program to return `True`, or the entry `No Special Chars` to return `False`.

By special character I mean `*&%` etc. A complete list can be found

By special character I mean `*&%` etc. A full list can be found [here](https://owasp.org/www-community/password-special-characters).

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly does "special character" mean in your context? You need to be very clear and specific in such questions.

Comment: What special characters do you mean? not text or numbers?

Comment: @Fredrik @%-_)(....

Comment: Which of all [characters](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/) are special? On the plus side, they have two dimensions: block (as shown on that webpage, and [general category](https://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values). One the downside, there are some really special features of text like combining characters, normal forms, direction reversing codepoints and variation selectors (for things like skin tone). [Confusables](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp) might be an issue and thereby be "special" to you. In short, your question is too broad, as it is now.

Answer (score 41):

Check for any of characters not being alphanumeric like:

```
any(not c.isalnum() for c in mystring)
```

Comment: This returns true for a string of whitespace

Comment: Apply replace space with nothing and strip to the string then.

Answer (score 24):

Give a try for:

```
special_characters = ""!@#$%^&*()-+?_=,<>/""
s=input()
# Example: $tackoverflow

if any(c in special_characters for c in s):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
 
# Response: yes
```

Comment: Can you please show your snippet attempts to answer the question? Always remember to follow [StackOverflow guidelines on how to answer a question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: The OWASP recommends the following list of special characters for passwords: (Escaped as a Python string) " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~" Source: https://owasp.org/www-community/password-special-characters

Comment: You can also use the "string.punctuation" as a special character list https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation

Comment: Imma use this in my app. I am not gonna use regex. this works fine

Comment: what does the 'c' represent here?

Answer (score 18):

Using `string.printable` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#string.printable)):

```
text = 'This is my text with special character ()'

from string import printable

if set(text).difference(printable):
    print('Text has special characters.')
else:
    print("Text hasn't special characters.")
```

Prints:

```
Text has special characters.
```

EDIT: To test only ascii characters and digits:

```
text = 'text%'

from string import ascii_letters, digits

if set(text).difference(ascii_letters + digits):
    print('Text has special characters.')
else:
    print("Text hasn't special characters.")
```

Answer (score 7):

A non-ideal but potential way to do it while I look for a better solution:

```
special_char = False
for letter in string:
    if (not letter.isnumeric() and not letter.isdigit()):
        special_char = True
        break
```

UPDATE: Try this, it sees if the regex is present in the string. The regex shown is for any non-alphanumeric character.

```
import re
word = 'asdf*'
special_char = False
regexp = re.compile('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+')
if regexp.search(word):
    special_char = True
```

Comment: How about using isalnum() instead?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a whitespace doesn't count as a special character.

```py
def has_special_char(text: str) -> bool:
    return any(c for c in text if not c.isalnum() and not c.isspace())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    texts = [
        'asdsgbn!@$^Y$',
        '    ',
        'asdads 345345',
        '123123',
        'hnfgbg'
    ]
    for it in texts:
        if has_special_char(it):
            print(it)
```

output:

```
asdsgbn!@$^Y$
123123
```

Answer (score 3):

Geeksforgeeks has a pretty good example using regex.

Source --> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-check-string-contains-special-character/
Special Characters considered -->  [@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]

```
# Python program to check if a string 
# contains any special character 

# import required package 
import re 

# Function checks if the string 
# contains any special character 
def run(string): 

    # Make own character set and pass  
    # this as argument in compile method 
    regex = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]') 

    # Pass the string in search  
    # method of regex object.     
    if(regex.search(string) == None): 
        print("String is accepted") 

    else: 
        print("String is not accepted.") 


# Driver Code 
if __name__ == '__main__' : 

    # Enter the string 
    string = "Geeks$For$Geeks"

    # calling run function  
    run(string)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply using the string method `isalnum()` like so:

```py
firstString = "This string ha$ many $pecial ch@racters"
secondString = "ThisStringHas0SpecialCharacters"
print(firstString.isalnum())
print(secondString.isalnum())
```

This displays:

```py
False
True
```

Take a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-isalnum/) if you'd like to learn more about it.

Comment: Simplest solution, you don't need to iterate over characters.