# Validating existence of symbols in input

Tags: python, validation

So I want to validate the input of a first name by checking if it has invalid characters. It works for blank entries and numbers but won't pick up any of the symbols.

```
import re
while True:
    f_name = input('First name: ').strip().lower()
    if f_name == '':
        print("* you haven't entered anything.")
        continue
    elif re.search('[0-9]', f_name):
        print("* entry can't contain numbers. please try again with only letters.")
        continue
    elif re.search('[~!@#£€$¢¥§%^&*/()\\-_+={}[]:;"\'<>,.?]', f_name):
        print("* entry can't contain symbols. please try again with only letters.")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

It works when only a few symbols are in the brackets but I need to check a wide range, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Don't, unless you want to run into problems when the Black Panther (T'challa) tries to sign up. Read
https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: It's only a grade 11 project for school, I don't think my teacher will be too picky with cases of characters in names xD

Comment: @DavidErickson sorry! I'm fairly new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use `[^\w/]|_`.

1. `[^\w/]` matches alphanumeric + `_` as well as `/`
2. `|_` excludes underscore since `_` is included by default with alphanumeric characters with [^\w/]:

---

```
import re
while True:
    f_name = input('First name: ').strip().lower()
    if f_name == '':
        print("* you haven't entered anything.")
        continue
    elif re.search('[0-9]', f_name):
        print("* entry can't contain numbers. please try again with only letters.")
        continue
    elif re.search('[^\w-]|_', f_name):
        print("* entry can't contain symbols. please try again with only letters.")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: In relation to the question I asked another answerer, could I exempt one particular symbol from this such as ' / ' ?

Comment: @carlym sorry I meant to say try `[^\w/]|_`

Comment: Probably remove your previous comment and edit this one to replace it instead of update it.

Answer (score 0):

Check for any of characters not being alphanumeric like:

any(not c.isalnum() for c in mystring)

This link may also help further: [How to check if a string has ANY special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57062794/how-to-check-if-a-string-has-any-special-characters/57062899)

Comment: Okay that works, but what if, for example in the case of a date being entered in the format MM/DD/YYYY, how do I make the ' / ' symbol exempt from that?

Comment: You could probably get past that by creating an exception. Try this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

```py
'[~!@#£€$¢¥§%^&*/()\\-_+={}[]:;"\'<>,.?]'
```

is not a valid regex. Well, at least not the regex that you're looking for. You have some unescaped characters in there, such as ] and " that messes it up. You can put it into a regex tester to see what I mean.

Doing it with a regex isn't the best option anyways. You have plenty of options for doing this, depending on your desired behavior. As others have mentioned, you could use `isalnum()` and `isalpha()` to check if a string only contains alphanumeric or alphabetical characters.

If you only want to exclude a special list of symbols and not other special symbols, you can use the intersection of two sets:

```py
DISALLOW_SYMBOLS = set("~!@#£€$¢¥§%^&*/()\\-_+={}[]:;\"'<>,.?")

f_name = input('First name: ').strip().lower()
name_set = set(f_name)
symbols = DISALLOW_SYMBOLS.intersection(name_set)
if symbols:
    print("* entry contains these symbols that are not allowed: ", symbols)
```