# How can I make a field validation in python, just for numbers and dashes? (0-9 and "-")

Tags: python, validation

I am reading a csv a file and I need to check if one of the fields has the correct content. It needs to be compound by numbers (0-9) and possible "-". For example: 
"12345" **Corrrect**
"12345-1" **Corrrect**
"12345a" **Incorrrect**

I tried using `int()`, but it only works for numbers, Dashes are acceptable as well.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: how would you treat strings that start or end with a dash - for example, like `12345-`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.isnumeric` combined with `str.replace` to strip the dashes before validation:

```py
s = "12345-1"
is_valid = s.replace('-', '').isnumeric()  # True
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57062843/13320545) which applies more generally.
To test a string run this, which can be adapted to work for the whole csv.

```
import re
word = '12345a'
special_char = False
regexp = re.compile('[^0-9-]')
if regexp.search(word):
    special_char = True
```